# How to print a range of lines with sed except the one matching the range-end pattern?

Tags: regex, linux, shell, sed, range

I wonder if there is a `sed`-only way to print a range of lines, determined by patterns to be matched, except the one last line matching the end pattern.

Consider following example. I have a file

```
line  1
line  2
line  3
ABC line  4
+ line  5
+ line  6
+ line  7
line  8
line  9
line 10
line 11
line 12
```

I want to get everything starting with `ABC` (including) and all the lines beginning with a `+`:

```
ABC line  4
+ line  5
+ line  6
+ line  7
```

I tried it with

```
sed -n '/ABC/I,/^[^+]/ p' file
```

but this gives one line too much:

```
ABC line  4
+ line  5
+ line  6
+ line  7
line  8
```

What's the easiest way (`sed`-only) to leave this last line out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There might be better ways but I could come up with this sed 1 liner:

```
sed -rn '/ABC/,/^[^+]/{/(ABC|^\+)/!d;p;}' file
```

#### Another sed 1 liner is

```
sed -n '/ABC/,/^[^+]/{x;/^$/!p;}' file
```

#### One more sed 1 liner (and probably better)

```
sed -n '/ABC/I{h;:A;$!n;/^+/{H;$!bA};g;p;}' file
```

Comment: @anubhava: Thank you. That's working. It's an interesting idea to solve it this way...

Comment: My pleasure, provided 3 sed 1 liners to achieve the goal.

Comment: Wow. I will have to have a further look on the 2nd and 3rd versions tomorrow. Currently I do not yet understand them ;) Thank you very much!

Comment: @anubhava: In the meantime I understood those commands. It's really amazing what you can do with a one-line stream-edit-command. I can go with all those versions for my current problem. But the first one has the advantage that it also works with several occurences of `ABC...`, also when there's no line following in the file and even when there's no line beginning with `+` following. The disadvantage is that I have to specify the pattern twice.

Comment: @bmk: I tested with those conditions and found that my 3rd option `/ABC/I{h;:A;n;/^+/{H;bA};g;p;}` is also working fine in those cases you mentioned like multiple instanced of `ABC` and no line following with `+` after ABC etc. If you come across a situation where 3rd option is not working just give me sample data and I will fix it.

Comment: @anubhava: It does not work if the `ABC`/`+` line is the last line of the file.

Comment: @bmk: You are right, I just made minor change `$!n` (means if NOT last line then next line) in 3rd option to make it work with that condition as well.

Comment: @anubhava: OK - that works if the last line is `ABC`, but if I add a line beginning with `+` sed seems to get into an infinite loop...

Comment: Actually I tried `$!ba` first but it failed for last line case because there is no next line after last line, so it is important to put `$!n` also so you are right but both places need `$!`. I edited the answer again.

Comment: @bmk You are most welcome, you due diligence helped me prepare this so big thanks to you too.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way (I'll learn something new if anyone can solve this with one call to sed), is to add an extra sed at the end, i.e.

```
sed -n '/ABC/I,/^[^+]/ p' file | sed '$d'
ABC line  4
+ line  5
+ line  6
+ line  7
```

Cheating, I know, but that is the beauty of the Unix pipe philosphy. Keep whitiling down your data until you get what you want ;-)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes that works. But i really hoped that there would be a way to do it with one call.  
But you're right - the pipe philosophy is really nice.

Comment: @bmk : thanks for the vote. I hope you get a complete answer. I'll be intersted to see what it is. I tried `/ABC/I,/^[^+]/-1{;p;}` which was the only thing I could think that *might* work, but it didn't. You might have better luck with an `ex` script. That could still be 1 inline statment, 1 prog invocation AND you can say :wq and not have to mess with managing filenames. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
 sed '/^ABC/{:a;n;/^\(ABC\|+\)/ba};d' file
```

EDIT: to allow adjacent `ABC` sections.

Comment: Thank you. That works fine for my given example - therefore +1. Unfortunately in reality there might be several adjacent `ABC` sections. In that case your `sed` command would print only every second one.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have selected your answer. But why aren't you using `/^(ABC|\+)/` ? Or am i mis-understanding your requirement?

If you want to find those `+` lines AFTER a search for ABC is found

```
awk '/ABC/{f=1;print} f &&/^\+/ { print }' file
```

This is much simpler to understand than crafting cryptic `sed` expressions. When ABC is found, set a flag. When lines starting with + is found and flag is set, print line.

Comment: I cannot use `/^(ABC|\+)/` because in this case all lines beginning with `+` are printed - regardless if they follow an `ABC` line or not. I guess you are right, that an `awk` script is a simpler solution but I prefer to use `sed` for some reasons (e.g. because there's some more processing already done with `sed` + I'm very interested in getting deeper insights into `sed`).

Comment: Shouldn't this awk command be: `awk '/ABC/{f=1; print} f &&/^\+/ { print }'` since OP wants to print those line with `ABC` also. However I think there still needs to be logic here to toggle `f` to 0 when lines with `^+` end otherwise even without next instance of ABC it will keep printing all lines with `^+`.

Comment: @anubhava, yes you are right. The ABC should be printed, as per OP's requirement.